# Swift: how to change a class into a struct

Tags: swift, class, model-view-controller, struct

I have written a very simple MVC program with a label and a button. The label displays the value of a counter which is incremented when the button is pressed.

The code that follows gives the model file and the view controller file. The model file is a class. 
That code works.

Here is the model file:

```
import Foundation

protocol MVCModelDelegate {
    var message: String {get set}
}

// when I change class to struct
// delegate is set to nil
// causing the program not to update the label
class Model {
    var delegate: MVCModelDelegate?
    var counter: Int
    var message: String {
        didSet {
            delegate?.message = model.message
        }
    }

    init(counter: Int, message: String) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.message = message
    }
}

// create instance
var model = Model(counter: 0, message: "")

// counting
func incrementCounter() {
    model.counter += 1
    model.message = "Counter Value:   \(model.counter)"
}
```

Here is the view controller file

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, MVCModelDelegate {
    // communication link to the model
    var model1 = model

    var message = model.message {
        didSet {
            didUpdateModel(message: message)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.model1.delegate = self
    }

    // update display
    func didUpdateModel(message: String) {
        Label1.stringValue = model1.message
    }

    // Label
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: NSTextField! {
        didSet {
            Label1.stringValue = " counter not started"
        }
    }

    // Button
    @IBAction func testButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        incrementCounter()
    }
}
```

Problem: I now want to change the code of the Model file to use a struct in place of a class as this very simple program does not need all the functionalities of a class. But as soon as I change class for struct. The program still runs, but the label is not updated as the delegate variable is set to nil and never gets another value.

Question: What am I missing?  The swift documentation encourages to use struct when possible. And I do not see in that code what could be a problem of transforming the class into a struct.

Comment: Try adding `mutating func incrementCounter()` when you change your class to a struct. I think by default that the properties of a `value` type can not be changed from within its instance methods.

Comment: @Simon. this would work if [func incrementCounter] was a method of the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct is immutable and it is not passed by reference like a class, but by value. This means that when you do

```
var model1 = model
```

You are creating a copy of `model`.

modifying `model1` will not propagate the changes to `model`, therefore all you do in `incrementCounter` is not reflected in your view controller.

If you want your `incrementCounter` to affect the viewController it must use the model in your viewController instance.

If your intention is to share the `model` properties and change the label value when this model is updated, struct is not the best choice.

Comment: @Guiseppe Lanza - You are right. But from what I see when I run the program, when I press the button in the VC, the counter is incremented in the model, the model.message is set, the didSet is run but as the delegate value is nil,  the instruction is aborted and nothing is passed back to the VC.

Comment: as I said model and model1 don't know each other. They are two different memory allocations. modifying one does not affect the other. this means that when you modify the delegate var of model1, this is not set in model, and when you modify the vars in model they are not modifying whatever is in model1.